# How to protect website username/passwords from RAM scraping malware

Tags: passwords, security, malware

I have recently read http://www.scmagazine.com.au/News/345109,memory-gaffe-leaves-aussie-bank-accounts-open-to-theft.aspx and I am very keen to learn how to protect my website users from this type of attack.

Can anyone provide more information on this attack and more specifically how to protect against it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the end of that article he writes "Westpac and NAB were the only banks tested to have encrypted the data." Seems like you would just need to encrypt it and not send anything in plain text.

Comment: Hmmm.. I've actually just had a delve into the Westpac JS - all they are doing is simply replacing the characters you select on their virtual keyboard with a different letter of the alphabet and sending that (which then gets "decoded" on the server side).